# How to prevent bash from exiting when command fails

Tags: bash

When I run bash on a docker container with

```
docker exec -it bash
```

Any command that fails (e.g. `cat nonexistent-file`) causes bash to quit

How can I stop that from happening?

I want bash to behave as per normal, i.e. a failed command just returns you to the bash prompt

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen by default. Can you post more detail like an exact `docker run` command, and the output you are getting?

Comment: I should clarify what I meant - the behavior you desire is what should happen by default. What you saw is not what should be happening.

Comment: Please share a representative example of such a *"failing command"*. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

OK, turns out in my `.bashrc` in my docker container, I was setting

```
set -e
```

which causes bash to exit immediately on failed commands.

Removing it solved my issue so this isn't really docker related...